# My Ubuntu doesn't suspend when I close the lid

Tags: 18.04, suspend, power-management

As in topic, my Ubuntu doesn't suspend when I close the lid, neither when I'm on battery or charger. I followed the steps advised in [this article](https://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/04/28/change-lid-close-action-ubuntu-18-04-lts/), but it didn't work - my Ubuntu still doesn't suspend and when I open the lid again I have the option to report a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Install Tweak Tool by these lines:

sudo apt-get install gnome-tweaks

Then, Disable the setting "Suspend when laptop lid is closed".
You are done..

Alternatively, you can do these CLI (using Commands) also,

• Open Terminal and type:
sudo gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf

• Uncomment the line "#HandleLidSwitch=suspend" by removing "#" in the beginning.

• Save and exit

• Now, Restart the Systemd service to apply changes via command:
systemctl restart systemd-logind.service